# Can .net assembly work on mac,linux

Tags: .net

**Pre .net :**
Before .net,language compiler (for example VB compiler) don't generates IL (intermediate language)
It only generates native code. so their was no portability in pre .net applications. They are failed to run on operating systems other than windows.

**With .net :**
.Net applications generates Assembly with intermediate language. which later convert by CLR (JIT) into native code. because of intermediate language there is portability.

BUT,

I googled some questions still in my mind 
Is dll run on mac/linux?
Is exe run on mac/linux?
Is Microsoft office run on mac/linux?

Believe me there are no answers which says clearly YES or NO. I got the answers with :
you have to **install something**...
you can **make it run**...

IS Microsoft provides **Operating system suitable** .net framework or CLR.
Really confused!!!

Please clear me if I am wrong.

Comment: You've got Mono : [link](http://www.mono-project.com/) for cross-OS compability which simulates the .NET framework

Comment: A clear and unambiguous answer of either "yes" or "no" would both be wrong, that's why you haven't seen such answers. "No" without further info would be wrong because you can make it run. "Yes" without further info would be wrong because it doesn't work by default.

Comment: Microsoft does not provide any means to run .NET assemblies on OS X or Linux. Can you run them? Perhaps. At the very least you need Mono installed on OS X and Linux, but even so, your assembly might not run because it uses framework types not available in Mono, or not available on OS X or Linux. So it is entirely correct that there are no answers which clearly says YES or NO, because neither is right, and yet neither is wrong.

Comment: so than what is use of assembly with intermediate language? It bring out by MS to have portability between various OS.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for .NET portability, then the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/) is the right place to start (http://www.mono-project.com/).

Mind you, you're asking a lot of different questions there... so as far as Microsoft Office running on Linux or Mac... Microsoft has [Microsoft Office for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac).  As far as Linux, there are layers such as [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) that allow you to run Windows programs on Linux.